# What does this syntax mean? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have been trying to learn Prolog and came across this syntax on some example code.

```
solve(Hs) :- Hs = [_,_,_,_,_],
    member(h(_, _, _, _, dog), Hs).
```

This is only a portion of the code, but I'm confused with the `h(_,_,_,_,dog)`does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underscores `_` just indicate that there is a value in that position, but we don't care about it.

The first part effectively says that `Hs` is a 5 item list.  The second part says that in that list of `Hs`, one of the items is a compound term `h/5` (h with 5 subterms) where the last is the atom, `dog`.

Answer (score 1):

All the underscores can match anything. It is a wild card. You are basically looking for a fact(?) with the last part equal to dog.